# SparkSql Catalyst extending Analyzer, Error with CatalystConf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extend the SparkSQL Catalyst analyzer with a few extra rules.

I am getting the following error:

```
**""" trait CatalystConf in package catalyst cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst """**
```

In my attempt I am doing the following:

```
class CustomSQLContext(sc: SparkContext) extends SQLContext(sc) {
    val an = new CustomAnalyzer(Map("testRule" -> testRule),catalog,functionRegistry,conf)
    override lazy val analyzer: Analyzer = an
  }

class CustomAnalyzer(rules: Map[String, Rule[LogicalPlan]], catalog: Catalog, registery: FunctionRegistry, conf: CatalystConf )
    extends Analyzer( catalog, registery, conf) {
    ......
    override lazy val batches = my_batch.toSeq ++ default_batches ++ Nil
  }
```

Any ideas how I can pass the conf to the customAnalyzer without this error?

I don't think it is an import error since it sees the package, but it cannot access the file.

I tried passing it as SQLConf but get a not found error and importing doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That class is *private*

```
package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst

private[spark] trait CatalystConf {
  def caseSensitiveAnalysis: Boolean
}
```

The only way to  use your code virtually untouched would be if your *own* code were to be placed into the `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst` package. That is not appealing. So you would have to copy the relevant code to your own package - not just extend it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I saw that is was private but I was hoping of a way to circumvent that. I am open to changing my approach, but I need a way to extend the Analyzer and don't know how.